# C++ реализация стека

Tags: c++, стек

Задача:Написать программу для моделирования Т-образного сортировочного узла на железной дороге с использованием контейнерного класса stack. Программа должна разделять на два направления состав, состоящий из вагонов двух типов (на каждое направление формируется состав из вагонов одно го типа). Предусмотреть возможность ввода исходных данных с клавиатуры и из файла.

Всем привет нужна помощь ввести и вывести данные с клавиатуры, вывод из файла я уже реализовал не могу понять как с клавы сделать помогите решить. Вот пример кода

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class CMyStack {
public:
    CMyStack();       
    ~CMyStack();      
    void Push(int d); 
    int Pop();
    bool isEmpty();
    void Print();

private:
    struct Node {
        int d;
        Node *p;
    };

    Node *top;
};

CMyStack::CMyStack() :top(NULL) {}

void CMyStack::Push(int d) {
    Node *pv = new Node; 
    pv->d = d; 
    pv->p = top; 
    top = pv;
}

int CMyStack::Pop() {
    if (isEmpty()) { 
        return -1;
    }

    int temp = top->d; 
    Node *pv = top;
    top = top->p; 
    delete pv;
    return temp;
}

bool CMyStack::isEmpty() { 
    return top ? false : true; 
}

void CMyStack::Print() {
    while (top) { 
        std::cout << Pop() << ' '; 
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

CMyStack::~CMyStack() {
    while (top) {
        Node *pv = top;
        top = top->p;
        delete pv;
    }
}

void emptyStack(CMyStack & stack);

int main() {
    CMyStack TrainBase, OneTrain, TwoTrain;
    std::ifstream in("trains.txt", std::ios::in);
    if (!in) {
        std::cout << "Cannot open file 'trais.txt' for reading" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    while (!in.eof()) {
        int pr;
        in >> pr;
        TrainBase.Push(pr);
    }

    while (!TrainBase.isEmpty()) {
        int pr = TrainBase.Pop();
        switch (pr) {
        case 1: 
            OneTrain.Push(pr);
            break;
        case 2:
            TwoTrain.Push(pr);
            break;
        }
    }

    OneTrain.Print();
    TwoTrain.Print();

    int _getch();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void emptyStack(CMyStack & stack) {
    if (stack.isEmpty()) {
        std::cout << "Stack is empty" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Stack is not empty" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Что содержит файл trains.txt?

Comment: Ну а в целом: не понимаю с чем у вас тут могут быть проблемы - просто там где у вас `in >> pr;` замените на `std::cin >> pr;`

Comment: из файла trains.txt выводятся данные в консоль, но я хочу в добавок чтобы с клавиатуры еще вводить и выводить. Просто курсовую готовлю и там нужна реализовать вывод данных с клавы и из файла

Comment: Так а почему не использовать то, что я писал выше?

Comment: так требует задание курсовой реализовать вывод данных двумя способами

Comment: Ну так вот они второй способ: тот что я описывал выше.

Comment: а вывод из файла при этом будет работать?

Comment: Ну так разделите: введите переменную, которая будет отвечать за способ ввода. Ну или если файл не доступен, то использовать ввод с клавы - что сдесь непонятного?

Comment: _"с использованием контейнерного класса stack"_ - надо не свой стек писать, а `std::stack` использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Если ваша проблеиа только в том, как  реализовать и вывод с файла и вывод с клавиатуры, то это легко решается, если вы свой код напишете в функции, а в программе просто вызовите функцию с файловым обьектом или с std::cin:

```
void programm(std::istream& input)
{
    CMyStack TrainBase, OneTrain, TwoTrain;
    std::stack TrainBase, OneTrain, TwoTrain;
    int pr;
    while (input >> pr)     // здесь я ввел поправку       
        TrainBase.Push(pr);     
    while (!TrainBase.isEmpty()) {
        int pr = TrainBase.Pop();
        switch (pr) {
            case 1: 
            OneTrain.Push(pr);
            break;
            case 2:
            TwoTrain.Push(pr);
            break;
        }
    }    
    OneTrain.Print();
    TwoTrain.Print();
}

int main()
{  
    std::ifstream in("trains.txt", std::ios::in);
    if (!in) {
        std::cout << "Cannot open file 'trais.txt' for reading" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    // вызываем функцию с программой для ввода с клавиатуры 
    programm(std::cin);
    // или для ввода из файла
    programm(in);
    return 0;
}
```

Я просто переписал ваш код с маленькой поправкой, но  не думаю, что это то, что требует ваша задача